# Infinite scroll and duplicated data

Tags: ios, postgresql, pagination, spring-data, infinite-scroll

I work on a mobile app which shows a stream of data fetched from the server. Initially the app fetches first page with 10 items. When user scrolls down, the app fetches the second page with next 10 items (in other words - infinite scroll). The problem I have is that when the user A fetches page number X it is possible, that the user B creates a new content on the server which modifies the resultset available for the user A. This means that if the user A tries to fetch X+1 page, it will contain previous item(s) which were "pushed back" by the new content. How to solve it? I came out with two solutions but I don't know which is better:

1. the mobile app remembers ids of already shown items and if in the next page there is an item which was already shown, it is not shown again.
2. the app remembers date of creation of the first item from the first page. When it fetches next pages, it additionaly sends this date to the server which adds this date to the sql query in order to maintain the same resultset

What do you think? Which is better? Are there better solutions?

UPDATE:

Imagine that I have a table 'queries' with columns 'queries_id' (integer, primary key), 'date_created' (timestamp). My query looks like this: select * from queries order by date_created desc. It is not true that date_created date_created increments with primary key incremenatation. I paginate data with Spring Data using Pageable object. Now the problem is that if new rows are created and they have date_created newer then previous newest row then they modify resultset.

Comment: If the pagination is done based on the record id then any modification of User B can not affect the results of user A. Ids are always incremental

Comment: Also you should tag technologies you are using to get more viewers in your question and hence more people to point out best practices

Comment: SQL queries do not take ids into account. They are ordered by date creation. But what you wrote is not true. If I make sql query which fetches results from a to b and then from c to d, then it is possible that during those queries new rows modify the resultset. This is my problem. Here you can see an example: http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/09/endless-scroll-and-real-time-data-solution-for-preventing-data-duplication/

Comment: `SQL queries do not take ids into account` then that is a wrong approach. Using date ranges for pagination is very inefficient.

Comment: So please explain better solution.

Comment: I think *you* should update OP with all necessary info. Technologies you use, how pagination is done etc in order to get more viewers and more help. Concerning my last part if you fetch records by id i.e. Primary Key then you would not have the problem you describe as each new insert would be incremental.

Comment: Add tags in your post with what you use.

Comment: What mobile app also. Android/iOS?

Comment: Now is better? I think I made it pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you do the pagination based only on the `date_created`.
I assume that you do your query with `ORDER BY date_created DESC` and you offset for the current page.
To avoid your problem you need to add the last id of the previous fetch in your query. I.e. `queries_id < last_id ORDER BY date_created ....` etc